# Is there a template way of storing and retrieving interfaces in a container?

Tags: c++

If we want to implement the the command pattern in C++ we normally have something like this -

```
struct Command {
   virtual void execute() = 0; 
   virtual ~Command() {}
};

struct Invoker {
  void enq(std::unique_ptr<Command> command) {
    commands_.push_back(std::move(command));
  }

  void invoke_all() {
    for (const auto& e : commands_) {
      e->execute();
    }
  }

  std::deque<std::unique_ptr<Command>> commands_;
};
```

However if I want to avoid polymorphic types and try to do this via generic programming, I get something like this -

```
template<class T>
concept Command = requires(T a)
{
    { a.execute() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct Invoker {

  template <Command T>
  void enq(T&& command) {
    commands_.push_back(std::any{std::forward<T>(command)});
  }

  void invoke_all() {
    for (const auto& e : commands_) {
      // what to do here?
    }
  }

  std::deque<std::any> commands_;
};
```

Now I know that it is probably impossible to achieve this without knowing all implementing types of the concept in advance. My question is, is falling back on polymorphic base types the best approach here? Or is there a more generic programming oriented design pattern?

The generalised problem I am trying to address here is - Given different types of objects which satisfy an interface. Is it possible to store those objects in a container. Retrieve them at a later time. And invoke a method satisfying the interface. All in a generic programming way.

Comment: The accepted way is type erasure, which is how `std::any` and `std::function` etc. are "meant" to be implemented and which relies on `virtual` methods. I don't think you get much better than that. `std::any` only "preserves" the `typeid` operation, `std::function` the `std::invoke`, and you want an instance of the pattern that preserves `execute`.

Comment: You're losing the type safety of C++. Wouldn't it be better to use a fixed function interface pattern.  E.g. `std::function<void()>`. Or what ever suits your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store different type in your container, you need interface or type-erasure.
The call to `execute` would call then virtual method or equivalent.

So you can indeed not require that class provided from user inherit from `Command` as long it satisfies some interface:

With `std::function`

```
template<class T>
concept Command = requires(T a)
{
    { a.execute() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct Invoker {

  template <Command T>
  void enq(T&& command) {
    commands_.emplace_back([c=std::move(command)](){c.execute();});
  }

  void invoke_all() {
    for (const auto& f : commands_) {
      f();
    }
  }

  std::deque<std::function<void()>> commands_;
};
```

With automatic inheritance:

```
template<class T>
concept Command = requires(T a)
{
    { a.execute() } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

struct ICommand {
   virtual void execute() = 0; 
   virtual ~ICommand() = default;
};

template <Command T>
struct CommandT : ICommand
{
   CommandT(T t) : t(std::move(t)) {}

   void execute() override { t.execute(); }

   T t;
};

struct Invoker {

  template <Command T>
  void enq(T&& command) {
    commands_.emplace_back(std::make_unique<CommandT<std::decay_t<T>>>(command));
  }

  void enq(std::unique_ptr<ICommand>&& c) { commands_.emplace_back(std::move(c)); }


  void invoke_all() {
    for (const auto& f : commands_) {
      commands_->execute();
    }
  }

  std::deque<std::unique_ptr<ICommand>>> commands_;
};
```

Comment: `std::function` is every bit as polymorphic as the original `Command`.